# How to draw a thematic map of counties within a state for united states of america?

Tags: geospatial

How to draw a thematic map of counties within a state for united states of america? From where I should get the geocodes data for boundaries?

Answer (score 1):

For counties within the US, the easiest (and most freely available) source is the US Census Bureau.   In particular, the [TIGER/Line Shapefiles](http://www.census.gov/geo/www/tiger/tgrshp2010/tgrshp2010.html)  provide the official view of information in ESRI Shapefile format, which is easy to convert to many other formats (not to mention, [well documented](http://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf)).

Here are the steps to retrieve the county shape data:

1. Visit the [TIGER/Line Shapefiles](http://www.census.gov/geo/www/tiger/tgrshp2010/tgrshp2010.html)  site
2. Choose **Counties (and Equivalent)** in the **Select a layer type** menu, and click **submit**
3. Either choose and individual state or choose **All States in one national file** and click **Download**

The national file is about 70MB

As for drawing it.   These are going to be all polygons, and you will likely not want to draw them all at the same time.   It's a bit of an art to manage this kind of data, especially on devices that may have smaller memory footprints (such as phones and the iPad).